# FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/49.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: read ECONNRESET error in running react native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I have an application file of react native that was running fine in vs code before but now whenever I tried to run it gives this error. I try to run it by
`PS C:\User\Desktop\ReactNativeApp> npx expo start`

```
Starting Metro Bundler

`FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/49.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: 
 read ECONNRESET
 FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/49.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: 
 read ECONNRESET
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\User\Desktop\ReactNativeApp\node_modules\node- 
  fetch\lib\index.js:1501:11)

at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)`
```

I have tried restarting and even create a new project but it is giving the same error. How can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: "npx expo start -c" worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77141412/23179463

Answer (score 10):

Start your server with

> npx expo start -c

inside your terminal

-c is short for --clear

Comment: yah its worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lately, my go-to has been:
`npm start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your network, In my case, it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First try running npx expo start --clear if that doesn't work for you then the problem is with your internet connection so switch to another network or restart your router. then you would be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Global CLI worked for me, but of course that the The global expo-cli package has been deprecated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).